# Can someone explain why I am getting a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I have a project that is getting a segmentation fault and I have no clue why. The project is to create a 2D matrix word puzzle and search for words based on input. I can get it to easily find words going from left to right, and right to left, but when I add in my top to bottom and bottom to top functions, i get a segmentation fault no matter what! I will attach my code so people can see what the problem could be:

```
//Checking for the first letter before going to sub categories
void checkForWord(char *str, char **puzzle, int rows, int columns) {
        int r,c,i=0;

         for(r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
          for(c = 0; c < columns; c++){
            if(puzzle[r][c] == str[i]) {
                if(c != columns) {
                    if(puzzle[r][c+1] == str[i+1]) {
                        if(restOfWordLR(str, puzzle, r, c+1, 2) == 1) {
                            lrCount++;
                            totalCount++;
                            printf("TesT\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(c != 0) {
                    if(puzzle[r][c-1] == str[i+1]) {
                        if(restOfWordRL(str, puzzle, r, c-1, 2) == 1) {
                            rlCount++;
                            totalCount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(r != rows) {
                    if(puzzle[r+1][c] == str[i+1]) {
                        if(restOfWordTB(str, puzzle, r+1, c, 2) == 1) {
                            tbCount++;
                            totalCount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(r != 0) {
                    if(puzzle[r-1][c] == str[i+1]) {
                        if(restOfWordBT(str, puzzle, r-1, c, 2) == 1) {
                            btCount++;
                            totalCount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please repost the code.

Comment: The code as quoted won't compile, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and be sure to post the full error message and stack trace if any.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(c != columns) {
     if(puzzle[r][c+1] == str[i+1]) {
```

This still access out of array boundary when `c == columns-1`, where `c != columns`, but `c+1 == columns` is still out of boundary.

The same issue also happens on the `if(r != rows)` code block.

You could change them into `if (c < columns-1)`. Be sure to review the correctness of the logic after modification.

Comment: Likewise in the next block for: 

    if (r!=rows) {
        if (puzzle[r+1][c]...

Comment: So, how should I go about fixing it? Cause I tried changing it to

Comment: @AdamAlred added possible fix

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but for the (c!= 0), would I need to change that to something like (c > 0) ?

Comment: @AdamAlred No need. Except in extreme condition (overflow, etc.) your for loop does not assign `c` as negative value. Thus `c != 0` and `c > 0` are kind of equivalent.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you so much man!

Comment: Hey, so it is working but for some reason, the occasional word will cause a segmentation fault but none of the others will.